# remote odbc connect - php and msaacess

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

im trying to connect php and msaccess

Im using the code below in connecting php and ms access and so far it working fine when i add System DSN to fetch database **locally**

but when the database is in remote location i receive the message connection failed [image]

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect('northwind','','');
if (!$conn)
  {exit("Connection Failed: " . $conn);}
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers";
$rs=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);
if (!$rs)
  {exit("Error in SQL");}
echo "<table><tr>";
echo "<th>Companyname</th>";
echo "<th>Contactname</th></tr>";
while (odbc_fetch_row($rs))
{
  $compname=odbc_result($rs,"CompanyName");
  $conname=odbc_result($rs,"ContactName");
  echo "<tr><td>$compname</td>";
  echo "<td>$conname</td></tr>";
}
odbc_close($conn);
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Just for information im working this is old server with winserver 2003 installed

Comment: Do you have write-permissions on the network drive? Do you have enough permissions to create a new file on the network drive? Does it work if you map the network drive?

Comment: this is my mistake , i used ip address instead of computer name..all now is working fine..Hope this will help someone..anyway thank you